# Flutter: Why does switching between Scaffolds based on a condition statement in the build function work, but doesn't work with custom Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a custom `Scaffold` to allow me to easily display `SnackBar` messages, regardless of what page was showing, called `MScaffold`. However, when I try to conditionally build one or the other of two possible `MScaffold`s, I get the same `MScaffold` again. When I do this with regular `Scaffold`s, the page switches fine, leading me to believe it has to do with the `MScaffold`. I can't figure out why, though. The only thing I can guess is that when you extend a `Widget`, certain properties must change, but I can't figure out why that would prevent `MyHomePage` from showing a different `MScaffold` (when, again, it shows a different `Scaffold` just fine).

I also tried this with a maximally minimal extension of `Scaffold`, and I found that only when I `override` the `build` method does it do this.

Somehow, when I `override` the `build` method of `ScaffoldState` in my custom `Widget`, `MScaffold`, it prevents the parent widget from rebuilding itself with a new `Widget` of the same type. I also found that when one of the options is a `Scaffold`, and the other option is an `MScaffold`, regardless of the order, it also switches fine. It's just when both options are an `MScaffold` that it doesn't switch anymore.

It seems like somehow the `MScaffoldState` is returning the same `build` result every time.

Here's the implementation (if you replace the two `MScaffold`s with `Scaffold`s, it works):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'PageSwitcher.dart';
import 'MScaffold.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MScaffold switch error',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'MScaffold switch error'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void _switchPage() {
    PageSwitcher().switchPage();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageSwitcher().pageNum == 1
        ? MScaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(widget.title),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Page 1',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: _switchPage,
              tooltip: 'Switch',
              child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
          )
        : MScaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(widget.title),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Page 2',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: _switchPage,
              tooltip: 'Switch',
              child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
          );
  }
}
```

Here's the class `PageSwitcher`, which is used to keep track of what page the app is on:

```
class PageSwitcher{
  static final PageSwitcher _thisClass = PageSwitcher._internal();
  PageSwitcher._internal();
  factory PageSwitcher(){
    return _thisClass;
  }
  int pageNum = 1;
  void switchPage(){
    pageNum = pageNum==1?2:1;
  }
}
```

The custom `Widget`, `MScaffold`, is a pretty minimally altered version of `Scaffold`, so I don't understand why this error is occurring.

Here's the page for `MScaffold`:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShowSnackBar {
  SnackBar currentSnackBar;
  int lastHideTime = -1; //in millisecondsSinceEpoch
  String _msg;
  bool isSnackBarVisible = false;
  static final _thisClass = ShowSnackBar._internal();
  ShowSnackBar._internal();
  factory ShowSnackBar() {
    return _thisClass;
  }
  ChangeNotifier showNotifier = ChangeNotifier();
  ChangeNotifier hideNotifier = ChangeNotifier();

  showText(String inputMsg) {
    _msg = inputMsg;
    currentSnackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(_msg));
    isSnackBarVisible = true;
    showNotifier.notifyListeners();
  }

  show(SnackBar inputSnackBar) {
    currentSnackBar = inputSnackBar;
    isSnackBarVisible = true;
    showNotifier.notifyListeners();
  }

  hide() {
    hideNotifier.notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MScaffold extends Scaffold {
  Key key;
  var appBar;
  var body;
  var floatingActionButton;
  var floatingActionButtonLocation;
  var floatingActionButtonAnimator;
  var persistentFooterButtons;
  var drawer;
  var endDrawer;
  var bottomNavigationBar;
  var bottomSheet;
  var backgroundColor;
  var resizeToAvoidBottomPadding;
  var resizeToAvoidBottomInset;
  var primary;
  var drawerDragStartBehavior;
  var extendBody;
  var extendBodyBehindAppBar;
  var drawerScrimColor;
  var drawerEdgeDragWidth;

  MScaffold({
    Key key,
    this.appBar,
    this.body,
    this.floatingActionButton,
    this.floatingActionButtonLocation,
    this.floatingActionButtonAnimator,
    this.persistentFooterButtons,
    this.drawer,
    this.endDrawer,
    this.bottomNavigationBar,
    this.bottomSheet,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.resizeToAvoidBottomPadding,
    this.resizeToAvoidBottomInset,
    this.primary = true,
    this.drawerDragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.start,
    this.extendBody = false,
    this.extendBodyBehindAppBar = false,
    this.drawerScrimColor,
    this.drawerEdgeDragWidth,
  })  : assert(primary != null),
      assert(extendBody != null),
      assert(extendBodyBehindAppBar != null),
      assert(drawerDragStartBehavior != null),
      super(key: key);

  @override
  ScaffoldState createState() {
    return MScaffoldState(
      key: key,
      appBar: appBar,
      body: body,
      floatingActionButton: floatingActionButton,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: floatingActionButtonLocation,
      floatingActionButtonAnimator: floatingActionButtonAnimator,
      persistentFooterButtons: persistentFooterButtons,
      drawer: drawer,
      endDrawer: endDrawer,
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
      bottomSheet: bottomSheet,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: resizeToAvoidBottomPadding,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: resizeToAvoidBottomInset,
      primary: primary,
      drawerDragStartBehavior: drawerDragStartBehavior,
      extendBody: extendBody,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: extendBodyBehindAppBar,
      drawerScrimColor: drawerScrimColor,
      drawerEdgeDragWidth: drawerEdgeDragWidth,
    );
  }
}

class MScaffoldState extends ScaffoldState {
  Key key;
  var appBar;
  var body;
  var floatingActionButton;
  var floatingActionButtonLocation;
  var floatingActionButtonAnimator;
  var persistentFooterButtons;
  var drawer;
  var endDrawer;
  var bottomNavigationBar;
  var bottomSheet;
  var backgroundColor;
  var resizeToAvoidBottomPadding;
  var resizeToAvoidBottomInset;
  var primary;
  var drawerDragStartBehavior;
  var extendBody;
  var extendBodyBehindAppBar;
  var drawerScrimColor;
  var drawerEdgeDragWidth;

  MScaffoldState({
    Key key,
    this.appBar,
    this.body,
    this.floatingActionButton,
    this.floatingActionButtonLocation,
    this.floatingActionButtonAnimator,
    this.persistentFooterButtons,
    this.drawer,
    this.endDrawer,
    this.bottomNavigationBar,
    this.bottomSheet,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.resizeToAvoidBottomPadding,
    this.resizeToAvoidBottomInset,
    this.primary = true,
    this.drawerDragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.start,
    this.extendBody = false,
    this.extendBodyBehindAppBar = false,
    this.drawerScrimColor,
    this.drawerEdgeDragWidth,
  })  : assert(primary != null),
      assert(extendBody != null),
      assert(extendBodyBehindAppBar != null),
      assert(drawerDragStartBehavior != null);

  Function() _listenerShow;
  Function() _listenerHide;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _listenerShow = () {
      if (mounted) {
        Scaffold.of(_scaffoldContext)
          .showSnackBar(ShowSnackBar().currentSnackBar)
          .closed
          .then((SnackBarClosedReason reason) {
          ShowSnackBar().isSnackBarVisible = false;
          ShowSnackBar().lastHideTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
        });
      }
    };

    _listenerHide = () {
      if (mounted) {
        Scaffold.of(_scaffoldContext).hideCurrentSnackBar();
      }
    };

    Future.microtask(() {
      if (ShowSnackBar().isSnackBarVisible) _listenerShow();
      ShowSnackBar().showNotifier.addListener(_listenerShow);
      ShowSnackBar().hideNotifier.addListener(_listenerHide);
    });
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    ShowSnackBar().showNotifier?.removeListener(_listenerShow);
    ShowSnackBar().hideNotifier?.removeListener(_listenerHide);
    super.dispose();
  }

  BuildContext _scaffoldContext;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: key,
      appBar: appBar,
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          _scaffoldContext = context;
          return body;
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: floatingActionButton,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: floatingActionButtonLocation,
      floatingActionButtonAnimator: floatingActionButtonAnimator,
      persistentFooterButtons: persistentFooterButtons,
      drawer: drawer,
      endDrawer: endDrawer,
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
      bottomSheet: bottomSheet,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: resizeToAvoidBottomPadding,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: resizeToAvoidBottomInset,
      primary: primary,
      drawerDragStartBehavior: drawerDragStartBehavior,
      extendBody: extendBody,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: extendBodyBehindAppBar,
      drawerScrimColor: drawerScrimColor,
      drawerEdgeDragWidth: drawerEdgeDragWidth,
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, `MScaffold` accepts the same arguments as `Scaffold` and produces a `Scaffold` with those arguments. The only thing it does differently is to work with the `ShowSnackBar` class to handle `SnackBar` messages. Other than that, it's just taking `Scaffold` arguments and then building a `Scaffold` with those arguments.

---

**SOLUTION**

The solution was Saed Nabil's suggestion plus changing `MScaffold({Key key...` to `MScaffold({this.key...` and `MScaffoldState({Key key...` to `MScaffoldState({this.key...` as it was not accepting keys.

The new presentation looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'PageSwitcher.dart';
import 'MScaffold.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MScaffold switch error',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'MScaffold switch error'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void _switchPage() {
    PageSwitcher().switchPage();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageSwitcher().pageNum == 1
        ? MScaffold(
      key: ValueKey(1),
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(widget.title),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Page 1',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: _switchPage,
              tooltip: 'Switch',
              child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            ),
          )
        : MScaffold(
      key:ValueKey(2),
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(widget.title),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Page 2',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: _switchPage,
              tooltip: 'Switch',
              child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

The new `MScaffold.dart` looks like this (with this design, you don't have to set the keys when you create a new `MScaffold` -- it takes care of that automatically):

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShowSnackBar extends ChangeNotifier {
  SnackBar currentSnackBar;
  int lastHideTime = -1; //in millisecondsSinceEpoch
  String _msg;
  bool isSnackBarVisible = false;
  static final _thisClass = ShowSnackBar._internal();
  ShowSnackBar._internal();
  factory ShowSnackBar() {
    return _thisClass;
  }
  ChangeNotifier showNotifier = ChangeNotifier();
  ChangeNotifier hideNotifier = ChangeNotifier();

  showText(String inputMsg) {
    _msg = inputMsg;
    currentSnackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(_msg));
    isSnackBarVisible = true;
    showNotifier.notifyListeners();
  }

  show(SnackBar inputSnackBar) {
    currentSnackBar = inputSnackBar;
    isSnackBarVisible = true;
    showNotifier.notifyListeners();
  }

  hide() {
    hideNotifier.notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MScaffold extends Scaffold {
  ValueKey key;
  var appBar;
  var body;
  var floatingActionButton;
  var floatingActionButtonLocation;
  var floatingActionButtonAnimator;
  var persistentFooterButtons;
  var drawer;
  var endDrawer;
  var bottomNavigationBar;
  var bottomSheet;
  var backgroundColor;
  var resizeToAvoidBottomPadding;
  var resizeToAvoidBottomInset;
  var primary;
  var drawerDragStartBehavior;
  var extendBody;
  var extendBodyBehindAppBar;
  var drawerScrimColor;
  var drawerEdgeDragWidth;

  MScaffold({
    this.key,
    this.appBar,
    this.body,
    this.floatingActionButton,
    this.floatingActionButtonLocation,
    this.floatingActionButtonAnimator,
    this.persistentFooterButtons,
    this.drawer,
    this.endDrawer,
    this.bottomNavigationBar,
    this.bottomSheet,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.resizeToAvoidBottomPadding,
    this.resizeToAvoidBottomInset,
    this.primary = true,
    this.drawerDragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.start,
    this.extendBody = false,
    this.extendBodyBehindAppBar = false,
    this.drawerScrimColor,
    this.drawerEdgeDragWidth,
  })  : assert(primary != null),
        assert(extendBody != null),
        assert(extendBodyBehindAppBar != null),
        assert(drawerDragStartBehavior != null),
        assert(
          !((key!=null
            &&key.value is Map<String,dynamic>)
            &&key.value.length==1
            &&key.value.containsKey('MScaffoldAutoKey')),
          "The Key you use for MScaffold cannot be a Map object that contains only one index "
            "named, 'MScaffoldAutoKey,' as this is reserved for MScaffold."
        ),
        super(key: key) {
    if (key == null) this.key = _autoKeyGen();
  }

  static List<Key> _autoKeys = [];
  bool _usesAutoKey = false;
  Key _autoKeyGen() {
    _usesAutoKey = true;
    Key retKey = ValueKey({'MScaffoldAutoKey': _autoKeys.length});
    _autoKeys.add(retKey);
    return retKey;
  }

  @override
  MScaffoldState createState() {
    return MScaffoldState(
      key: key,
      appBar: appBar,
      body: body,
      floatingActionButton: floatingActionButton,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: floatingActionButtonLocation,
      floatingActionButtonAnimator: floatingActionButtonAnimator,
      persistentFooterButtons: persistentFooterButtons,
      drawer: drawer,
      endDrawer: endDrawer,
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
      bottomSheet: bottomSheet,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: resizeToAvoidBottomPadding,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: resizeToAvoidBottomInset,
      primary: primary,
      drawerDragStartBehavior: drawerDragStartBehavior,
      extendBody: extendBody,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: extendBodyBehindAppBar,
      drawerScrimColor: drawerScrimColor,
      drawerEdgeDragWidth: drawerEdgeDragWidth,
      autoKeys: _usesAutoKey ? _autoKeys : null,
    );
  }
}

class MScaffoldState extends ScaffoldState {
  Key key;
  var appBar;
  var body;
  var floatingActionButton;
  var floatingActionButtonLocation;
  var floatingActionButtonAnimator;
  var persistentFooterButtons;
  var drawer;
  var endDrawer;
  var bottomNavigationBar;
  var bottomSheet;
  var backgroundColor;
  var resizeToAvoidBottomPadding;
  var resizeToAvoidBottomInset;
  var primary;
  var drawerDragStartBehavior;
  var extendBody;
  var extendBodyBehindAppBar;
  var drawerScrimColor;
  var drawerEdgeDragWidth;
  var autoKeys;

  MScaffoldState({
    this.key,
    this.appBar,
    this.body,
    this.floatingActionButton,
    this.floatingActionButtonLocation,
    this.floatingActionButtonAnimator,
    this.persistentFooterButtons,
    this.drawer,
    this.endDrawer,
    this.bottomNavigationBar,
    this.bottomSheet,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.resizeToAvoidBottomPadding,
    this.resizeToAvoidBottomInset,
    this.primary = true,
    this.drawerDragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.start,
    this.extendBody = false,
    this.extendBodyBehindAppBar = false,
    this.drawerScrimColor,
    this.drawerEdgeDragWidth,
    this.autoKeys,
  })  : assert(primary != null),
        assert(extendBody != null),
        assert(extendBodyBehindAppBar != null),
        assert(drawerDragStartBehavior != null);

  Function() _listenerShow;
  Function() _listenerHide;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _listenerShow = () {
      if (mounted) {
        Scaffold.of(_scaffoldContext)
            .showSnackBar(ShowSnackBar().currentSnackBar)
            .closed
            .then((SnackBarClosedReason reason) {
          ShowSnackBar().isSnackBarVisible = false;
          ShowSnackBar().lastHideTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
        });
      }
    };

    _listenerHide = () {
      if (mounted) {
        Scaffold.of(_scaffoldContext).hideCurrentSnackBar();
      }
    };

    Future.microtask(() {
      if (ShowSnackBar().isSnackBarVisible) _listenerShow();
      ShowSnackBar().showNotifier.addListener(_listenerShow);
      ShowSnackBar().hideNotifier.addListener(_listenerHide);
    });
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    ShowSnackBar().showNotifier?.removeListener(_listenerShow);
    ShowSnackBar().hideNotifier?.removeListener(_listenerHide);
    autoKeys?.remove(key);
    super.dispose();
  }

  BuildContext _scaffoldContext;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: key,
      appBar: appBar,
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          _scaffoldContext = context;
          return body;
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: floatingActionButton,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: floatingActionButtonLocation,
      floatingActionButtonAnimator: floatingActionButtonAnimator,
      persistentFooterButtons: persistentFooterButtons,
      drawer: drawer,
      endDrawer: endDrawer,
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
      bottomSheet: bottomSheet,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: resizeToAvoidBottomPadding,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: resizeToAvoidBottomInset,
      primary: primary,
      drawerDragStartBehavior: drawerDragStartBehavior,
      extendBody: extendBody,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: extendBodyBehindAppBar,
      drawerScrimColor: drawerScrimColor,
      drawerEdgeDragWidth: drawerEdgeDragWidth,
    );
  }
}
```

And it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happing because there is no keys provided to your stateful widgets of `MScaffold` type

you can solve this by providing proper keys when constructing your scaffold objects like this

```
    MScaffold(
      key: ValueKey('1'),
      ...
)

    MScaffold(
      key: ValueKey('2'),
      ...
)
```

Comment: I added the keys exactly like you said and it's still having the same issue

Comment: I figured it out, you were right. The `MScaffold` wasn't setting the key. I had to change `MScaffold({Key key...` to `MScaffold({this.key...` and similarly, `MScaffoldState({Key key...` to `MScaffoldState({this.key...` and now it works.